# Installation with Create React App

Tags: babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I'm sorry for asking what may be an obvious question to most, but I'm lost.  I have created a react project with create-react-app.  I want to add a third party library (Ant Design UI Framework) that uses .css styles. Ant will use global .css and the rest of my application can then use styleName.

After running `npm install babel-plugin-react-css-modules --save` what do I have to do to get this running?  The documentation references the configuration but the individual steps required properly configure the app aren't clear at all—at least to me.

Can someone help with a bit of an "idiot's guide" to setting this up, and detail some of the steps?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

[Ant Design](http://ant.design/) also have react native library as you can see [here](https://mobile.ant.design/)

You just need to run the following command on your project root to install it:

```
$ npm install antd-mobile --save
```